# DeprecationWarning on salt-minion

Tags: debian, salt-stack

I have a salt-master (0.17.5) and a salt-minion (0.17.5) on two Debian machine (Debian 8 - Jessy).

When I launch this command `salt '*' cp.get_file salt://file /file`, I have this warning on my salt-minion :

`[WARNING] /usr/lib/.../minion.py:594: Deprecation Warning: Master pub message signing is disabled but we received a signature for this message. Most likely this means that your masters and minions are not the same version...`

Why I have this warning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem !

It is necessary to use `salt-cp '*' /file/src.txt /file/dest.txt` instead of `salt '*' cp.get_file salt://file/src.txt /file/dest.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I also was seeing such warnings periodically in the minions logs. Unfortunately, they only popup from time to time, so reproducing them is a bit tricky. It seems, that they are specific to the `0.17.5` version only.

Here is the quote from the [configuration file](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/0.17/conf/master#L191-205) that explains where those warnings come from:

> Signature verification on messages published from the master.
>   This causes the master to cryptographically sign all messages published to 
>   its event bus, and minions then verify that signature before acting on the 
>   message.
>
> This is False by default.
>
> Note that to facilitate interoperability with masters and minions that are 
>   different versions, if `sign_pub_messages` is `True` but a message is 
>   received by a minion with no signature, it will still be accepted, and a 
>   warning message will be logged.
>
> Conversely, if `sign_pub_messages` is `False`, but a minion receives a 
>   signed message it will be accepted, the signature will not be checked, and 
>   a warning message will be logged. This behavior will go away in Salt 
>   0.17.6 (or Hydrogen RC1, whichever comes first) and these two situations 
>   will cause minion to throw an exception and drop the message.
>
> `sign_pub_messages: False`

Since I've changed configuration to:

```
sign_pub_messages: True
```

I haven't seen those warnings in the logs anymore(but see the remark on reproducing).